# Magento 2 site does not load gif images

Tags: magento2, image, gif

I have a testimonials page, where my customer has added a .gif image. The image is not getting loaded on the frontend , hence alternate image text getting displayed.
This is the code

```
<img src="../../../js/tiny_mce/plugins/emotions/img/smiley-kiss.gif" alt="Kiss" title="Kiss" border="0">
```

On inspecting when I hover on this code, it shows Could not load image
How to resolve this?

Comment: Try opening the image path in a separate tab and check if the image exists.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I am not understanding what is the exact path from this. Can u tell me?

Comment: Inspect your image element in the browser and go to image path, right-click on it and select open in new tab. It will automatically open the image path.

Comment: It is showing 404 not found error

Comment: Can u please suggest something?

Comment: If you are getting 404 then it means that the path you are using is wrong. Please search for the file in your code and get correct file path.

Comment: path is correct